# Anachronism to describe a practice considered outdated

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Is it correct to describe a practice that is considered outdated, and has been superceded by other more appropriate practices, an anachronism?

I ask because the usual context I read anachronistic in is related to errors in chronology, rather than a practice that is now out of place.

To give a couple of examples:

"Johnny made phone calls using the old phone box at the bottom of the street. This is an anachronism peculiar to him alone"

"Debbie forced her guests to address her as ma'am, which is an anachronistic practice".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I first learned the word *anachronism* aged 15, when studying Shakespeare's *Julius Caesar* for GCE O Level. In one particular scene a clock strikes. Whilst clocks were around in Shakespeare's time they most definitely were not a feature of Ancient Rome. Our teacher told us it was an *anachronism*. So I have lived with the idea that something which belongs to the writer's/speaker's own period, but would have been unknown in the period being reported, is an ***anachronism***.

But nowadays I hear *anachronism* frequently being used to flag up anything that is out of date to the present time e.g. the use of a landline phone by a teenager.

Oxford Dictionaries online gives its meaning as : *a thing belonging or appropriate to a period other than in which it exists, especially a thing which is conspicuously old-fashioned: e.g. the town is a throwback to medieval times, an anachronism that has survived the passing years.*

**The OED is instructive in this matter. It divides *anachronism* into two senses (see below). Clearly my Shakespeare example belongs to the first, and it could equally be called a *prochronism*, which definition I also give below.

OED - ***Anachronism***

> 1. An error in computing time, or fixing dates; the erroneous reference of an event, circumstance, or custom to a wrong date. Said
>      etymologically (like prochronism) of a date which is too early, but
>      also used of too late a date, which has been distinguished as
>      parachronism.
> 2. Anything done or existing out of date; hence, anything which was proper to a former age, but is, or, if it existed, would be, out of
>      harmony with the present; also called a practical anachronism. Also
>      transf. of persons.

***Prochronism***

> An error in chronology that places an event earlier in time than its
>   true date. Cf. anachronism n.

Comment: Thank you. Is there another word that would fit in place of anachronism to avoid the controversy?

Comment: @user2321 I think, given the dictionary definition I have just quoted, your examples make correct use of the word.

Comment: @user2321 If you see my further edit, it clarifies the position with reference to the OED.